# Do bash script and command grep treat single quote differently

Tags: linux, bash

In Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide, I find

> Within single quotes, every special character except ' gets
>   interpreted literally.

So I think  `grep '\<the\>' file.txt` would search `\<the\>`, instead of word `the`. But it searches `the` indeed.

```
#!/bin/bash

grep '\<the\>' file.txt
```

**Added**
Maybe I don't describe my question clearly.In man page,

> Enclosing characters in single quotes preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes.

So my question is: Now that bash would regard enclosing characters in single quote as the literal value, why `'\<the\>'` is treated as `the` in grep? Is it `grep` own characteristic,differing from bash?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable

Comment: Mandatory xkcd: https://m.xkcd.com/1638/

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, *`bash`* will pass your string literally.

It is *`grep`* that interpretes the string (as a regular expression). If you want to avoid that, **use `grep -F`**. With that option, `grep` will search literally for the given string.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add another backslash `\` to match the whole pattern, as the symbols `\<` and `\>` are special to `grep`.  Quoting the manpage: `man grep`

> The Backslash Character and Special Expressions
>
> ```
>   The symbols \< and \> respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end
>   of  a  word.
> ```

[image]

Comment: Indeed, `grep` is a poor example for understanding quoting, because many of the characters in regular expressions have a special meaning to `grep`.